# How to fetch the immediate tag for an element using contains text in Selenium Java

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have to fetch the tag under which the text is visible. But if we use the getTagName for all tags containing the text, then even the parent elements shows the same text.

```
<ul> <li> The Text </li> </ul>
```

In the above case, if we use contains text to fetch the tag then both ul and li would be selected. If I don't want to mention exactly li in the query, is there any generic way to get the immediate tag as li for The Text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Java? Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to find an element having no child elements and containing that text.
The XPath locator for this will be:

```java
//*[not(child::*) and text()='your text']
```

So the command will be

```
String tag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[not(child::*) and text()='your text']")).getTagName();
```

Comment: Since you didn't mention your programming language I used Java. For other languages it will be similar, with slight changes

Answer (score 0):

okay, I think if you can locate an element `uniquely` in **DOM**, then you can fetch the tag name as well.

the element has to be unique like **1/1 matches in nodes.**

what I would suggest is to use **xpath** like below :-

```
//ul//li[contains(text(), 'The Text')]
```

or

```
//li[contains(text(), 'The Text')]
```

if they happen to present multiple time then apply xpath indexing :-

```
(//ul//li[contains(text(), 'The Text')])[1]
```

or

```
(//li[contains(text(), 'The Text')])[1]
```

in code you can use it like this :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath((//ul//li[contains(text(), 'The Text')])[1]).tag_name)
```

Now, it's a skill to find 1/1 matching node in HTML node, you can share more HTML content, and I can look for more constructive xpath.

Comment: Yes but it will return both ul and li

Comment: how are you retrieving it ?

Comment: If I use the same code as you shared, it would show multiple match. As ul and li both has same text.

Comment: It's mentioned in the question.

Comment: no that is not enough, I need to see more outer HTML ? Is website public  ?

Comment: see, basically you need to locate a unique tag in DOM, and then you can fetch the tag name, respectively. Now it looks like above solution will not work for sure. See above, I have updated my answer,  but would not be enough until I see your website or page resource.